# PowerShell Add-Type not behaving as expected

Tags: powershell

Can anyone explain why the following (using the `System` namespace qualifer) works:

```
Add-Type @"
public class BitValueChecker
{
    public static bool IsBitSetZeroBased(uint value, uint bitNumber)
    {
        if (bitNumber < 0 || bitNumber >= 32)
            throw new System.Exception("Invalid bit number must be >= 0 and <= 31");

        uint checkValue = value & System.Convert.ToUInt32(System.Math.Pow(2, bitNumber));
        return checkValue > 0;
    }
}
"@
```

while the below (essentially identical) snippet causes PS to complain that `Exception`, `Convert` and `Math` "do not exist in the current context"?

```
Add-Type @"
public class BitValueChecker
{
    public static bool IsBitSetZeroBased(uint value, uint bitNumber)
    {
        if (bitNumber < 0 || bitNumber >= 32)
            throw new Exception("Invalid bit number must be >= 0 and <= 31");

        uint checkValue = value & Convert.ToUInt32(Math.Pow(2, bitNumber));
        return checkValue > 0;
    }
}
"@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second code you have to add

```
Add-Type @"
using System;

public class BitValueChecker
{
....
```

Like in a c# code.

Comment: Beat me to it.   What's annoying is this bit in the PS docs: "By default, Add-Type references the System namespace."

Comment: if use parameter -membertype the system namespace is added !

Comment: @David Pope - What annoying bit? You are confusing between referencing and using. Even in Visual Studio, you have to reference and also do the using. Just that when you create a project System is referenced and there is a using System added as well.

Comment: Gah, n00b mistake... so used to Visual Studio and auto-added default usings. Like David, I do wish that the help would be updated to something like "By default, Add-Type references the System namespace (note: this does not mean it implicitly uses that namespace)".

Comment: @manojlds - No I'm not; I know the difference between them.  The documentation I quoted is from the "-UsingNamespace" switch, and the way it's worded suggests (misleadingly) that you don't need to specify it in your own logic because it's already done for you.  There's a separate switch for -ReferencedAssemblies, which states the default of referencing System.dll (Note the ".dll" on the end.)

Comment: @David Pope - `UsingNameSpace` and this one `TypeDefinition` are different paramter sets and are different. In that case, you will be doing a memeber definition and there `System` is already "used" ( in addition to being referenced, of course). The docs are fine in my opinion :) Except what @Ian Kemp suggests of explicitly saying that you have use namespaces.

Comment: @manojlds - Of course they are in different parameters sets.  I know _why_ the thing operates as it does.  But the docs are annoyingly flawed.  The parameter details are listed in alphabetical order, not grouped by parameter set.  If you want to have a clear picture of which parameters are functionally related, you have to read the "wall of text" and carefully compare to see which ones are NOT included in a given parameter set.  There's room for improvement, although perhaps they're well-suited for the way your own mind works.